# How to get all the values of a column inside a while loop and put those values into an array

Tags: php, mysql

Below I have a table that displays the data from MySQL, in the database, there's three column for storing different languages of msg (ie traditionalmessage,
simplifiedmessage &engmessage).

Each individual can pick their preferred language, in the `view page`, there's an `msg column`, it will show people's msg with their preferred languages

Like this

```
 People      Language       Msg
 A            繁體           物理治療
 B            Eng           Physiotherapy
```

---

```
 <table>

  <?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
 FROM treatmentdetail WHERE
 language ='繁體' OR language ='ENG' OR language ='简体'");?>
 <?php

  $specific = [];

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {?>

  <tr>

  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" size="1" name="people[]"  
  value="<?php echo $row['people'] ?>"></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" size="1" name="language[]"  
  value="<?php echo $row['language'] ?>"></td>


  <td width="200px"><input class="form-control" type="text" size="1" 
  name="msg[]" value="
  <?php if($row['language'] == '繁體')
  {
  echo  $row['traditionalmessage'];}

  else if($row['language'] == 'ENG')
  {
  echo $row['engmessage'];}

  if($row['language'] == '简体')
  {
  echo  $row['simplifiedmessage'];} ?>">
  </td>
```

Close the table

```
 <?php
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";echo "</form>";?>
```

Now I'd like to  `get all the values of the msg column` and put them in an array called $specific

```
     <?php $specific = [
                       "message" => $row["engmessage"]
                   ];?>
```

Here I just hard coded to get the values of all message. But as there are gonna be traditionalmessage & simplifiedmessage as well. So it has to be dynamic.

So how can I get the all the values of the msg column (which may have values retrieved from multiple database columns

```
i.e. traditionalmessage/
simplifiedmessage /engmessage)
```

and put those values into an array

Hope u understand what I meant.

Many thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, you'd normally store something like a language_id and then select the language based upon a hidden id within a form.

Comment: Now i can display the msg according to the language choice of individual in the page, just dont know how to get those values from msg column inside a while loop and put them in an array

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer answer questions relating to this ancient, insecure, and deprecated API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get my desired result with the use of the if else statement. I am aware that there's certainly better answer out there. IF u happen to have one, please share . Thanks again to those who have helped along the way.

```
 if($row['language'] == '繁體')
 {
  $specific[] = [
                 "message" => $row["traditionalmessage"]

 ];}

  else if($row['language'] == '简体')
 {
  $specific[] = [
                 "message" => $row["simplifiedmessage"]          

 ];}

  else if($row['language'] == 'ENG')
  {
  $specific[] = [
                 "message" => $row["engmessage"]

 ];}
```

Answer (score 1):

What problem? As I understand you need to extract all columns with message and loop by them. You know all column names or you need to determine it dynamically?  If you know it before, you can loop over `$row` array and extract needed values into an array.

```
    foreach ($row as $key) {
        //ignore columns with no 'message' in title
        if (FALSE === strpos($key, 'message')) continue;

        // do with $row[$key] what you want
    }
```

**As respected member Strawberry said you need to use mysqli (mysql improved or pdo, or mysqlnd) extension
to work with DB instead of deprecated and obsolete mysql extension.**

**General advice**
You table structure is wrong if you need to add new columns for each new language. You need to rethink you table structure. Google about 'db normalisation'.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, will look into it